# Getting and setting the nonce for a transaction

Tags: nonce

I'm using a javascript library (etheremjs) to sign a transaction. When creating it, it asks for the nonce field. I researched about it and partially understood it. But my main problem is:

How do I actually get it? Is the nonce a lifetime transaction number of that wallet or just a number for a set of transactions in a period of time? Does it start at 0 or 1? Is it public? How can I know what nonce I should use for a new transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nonce in the main ethereum network starts at 0 for each account and increases each time a transaction originates *from* that account.

You can just count the outbound transactions on etherscan.io, or you can call `eth_getTransactionCount` (or `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` if you're using that) on any node. Here's a way to do it via Etherscan's API:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionCount&address=0xYourAddressHere&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

The result is the number of outbound transactions that have happened so far, and thus also the correct nonce to use for the next transaction.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/) you can fetch it through the [provider](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/) as below:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const { ethereum } = window;

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider?.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(
                       CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
                       CONTRACT_ABI,
                       signer
);
const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(contract.address);

const tx = await contract.methodName(param1, param2, {
                gasLimit:gasLimit,
                gasPrice:gasPrice,
                value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
                nonce:nonce,
            });
```

**Step 2: Reset your Metamask account.**

Sometimes the issue is with your metamask account and needs to be reset to get the correct customer nonce value.

To reset your account:

Click Metamask Icon > Advanced Setting > Reset Account

[image]