# Webj3 erc20 specify nonce for token transfer

Tags: web3j, nonce

How do you specify a nonce when sending erc20 tokens using web3j?

Answer (score 1):

The nonce in a transaction is the number of transactions by  the sender you can not set this.

It is to prevent double spending. This is not to be confused with the proof of work nonce.

[Getting and setting the nonce for a transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33295/getting-and-setting-the-nonce-for-a-transaction)

[What is nonce in Ethereum? How does it prevent double spending?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27432/what-is-nonce-in-ethereum-how-does-it-prevent-double-spending)

Dear mod if you delete this again you really shouldn't be moderating an Ethereum stackexchange...

Comment: This doesnt explain how it differs from ERC20 Tokens? Is the nonce the same for both?